# Using a link to display an image on the same page

Tags: html, image, zooming, hyperlink, scaling

I have a large group of thumbnail images, all the same size.

I'd like for the user to be able to click a thumbnail image to display the full version of that image on the same page.

The full images are all different sizes (it's characters I've designed) and they are in proportion to one another so I'd also like to fix the zoom percentage for each character image. The area of space I have to work with is only 600px wide and some of the images are larger than that, so some sort of relative scaling has to be applied.

Comment: I would suggest using [Fancybox](http://www.fancybox.net). It's pretty easy to use and you can change the jQuery and styles to your liking.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going to go with Gallerific because it's Open-Source-ish. Not that I intensely believe in that as a business model-- Just because I'm broke. Fancybox looks nice though.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use a third party plugin for this and save yourself a lot of time

Two favorites:

- [Fancybox](http://www.fancyapps.com/fancybox/)
- [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/)

Comment: Thanks. I think I'm going to go with Gallerific because it's Open-Source-ish. Not that I intensely believe in that as a business model-- Just because I'm broke. Fancybox looks nice too.

Answer (score 0):

You should get Javascript knowledge of such this action...

Premium readymade scrips available here http://www.magictoolbox.com/magiczoom/examples/

This Demo site..

Good Luck !

Comment: Actually-- sorry about that-- they seem to all be working fine now. As a matter of fact, this set might be the most relevant to what I was looking for. Thanks.